# Querying a MySQL db representation of a tree

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that represent parent/child nodes, their types, and their relationships:

Table 1

```
|  nodeID  |  node  |  name  |  type    |
|   1      |   A    |  test  |  Type A  |
|   2      |   B    |  abcd  |  Type B  |
|   3      |   C    |  defg  |  Type C  |
```

Table 2

```
|  parentNodeID  |  childNodeID  |
|      1         |       2       |
|      1         |       3       |
```

I would like to write a query where I find children nodes of Type B that do not have a parent of Type C.

I've tried

```
select node from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.nodeID=t2.childNodeID
  where Type="Type B"
    and t2.parentNodeID not in (select nodeID from t1 where type="Type C)
```

This is not working as expected. Am I doing this correctly? Is there an easier way?

Comment: What specifically about your query is not working as expected (I'm assuming it's not the obvious typo that would give a syntax error). Can you give an example where your query fails to give the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT node
FROM Table1
WHERE type = 'Type B'
AND nodeID NOT IN (
   SELECT T2.childNodeID
   FROM table1 T1
   JOIN table2 T2
   ON T2.parentNodeId = T1.nodeId
   WHERE T1.type = 'Type C'
)
```

It means something like this: Find all nodes of type b that are not one of (the child nodes that have a parent node of type c).